# iOS Storyboard: Statusbar color

Tags: ios, colors, storyboard, statusbar

I´m trying to change the statusbar Color in storyboard, but it doesn´t work. The bar is gray, but i want to have a black bar. I know, i can change that with the folowing code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];
```

But when the app starts, the statusbar changes to gray and then to black. That doesn´t look fine.

I hope, you can help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend set status bar style in %AppName%-Info.plist of your project.
[image]